# i18n error --translation tags not working

Tags: javascript, i18next

I want to use the i18n translation function for a string containing html tags and text. My js program returns this string for backend Purpose. This is how I used the function:

```
i18n.t("Manage your subscriptions__-link__ on your Streams page__-closelink__.",{link:'<a href="#streams/all">',closelink:'</a>'});
```

The link `'<a href="#streams/all">'` is being translated into `<a href=\'#streams/all\'>`.

Answer (score 0):

that is escaped...default on i18next is set to escape interpolated content to save you from xss attacks.

you can unescape -> learn more https://www.i18next.com/interpolation.html#unescape